# How can I force ModalBottomSheet to not be dragged by user?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I have an Android project with Compose and i've implemented a ModalBottomSheet that is completely showed when pressing a button.
The problem happens when you drag the ModalBottomSheet and you hide it to the half. I want to make that this behavior is not possible, i want the card to have 2 positions, completely visible or hidden. Do you know how is possible to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid half-expanded state, define bottomSheetState as below:

```
 val bottomSheetState =
        rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden, confirmStateChange = {
            it != ModalBottomSheetValue.HalfExpanded
        })
```

And along with it, use below code in coroutineScope or LaunchedEffect to show expanded state directly whenever you want to show sheet:

```kotlin
bottomSheetState.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded)
```